# How to add border line in figures in latex overleaf

Tags: graphics, floats

My code is below:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]

\centering
     \includegraphics[height=5cm, width=15cm,]{screenshot/sa.png}
\caption{ Rapid Application Development}
\label{fig:figure2.1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please clarify what you would like to achieve. E.g., where should the "border line" be drawn?

Comment: better to only use one of these options or you will distort the image `[height=5cm, width=15cm,]` also `[!h]` should be avoided (and usually generates a warning). Depending what you mean, perhaps `\fbox{\includegraphics...}}` for the border

Comment: yes it works thanks